# Spark Streaming:java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

i am running a streaming job on CDH cluster and get error, and the cdh spark version is 1.2.0-cdh5.3.8, but i need spark2.1.0, so i have downloaded the apache spark and builded it(spark version: 2.1.0-cdh5.3.8,hadoop version=2.5.0-cdh5.3.8).

error message is below:

```
17/04/14 18:12:34 ERROR server.TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 4724089633860239943
java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7521802526148376080, local class serialVersionUID = -2941674837829752814
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:582)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:159)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : ztdm006:8041
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Received 1 containers from YARN, launching executors on 0 of them.
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1488960736410_229415_01_000004 on host: ztdm009 (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 1)
17/04/14 18:12:35 WARN yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000004 on host: ztdm009. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000004
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/04/14 18:12:35 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000004 on host: ztdm009. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000004
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1488960736410_229415_01_000005 on host: ztdm010 (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 1)
17/04/14 18:12:35 WARN yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000005 on host: ztdm010. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000005
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 3 requested
17/04/14 18:12:35 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000005 on host: ztdm010. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
```

Container id: container_1488960736410_229415_01_000005
     Exit code: 1
     Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:543)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:460)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:707)
         at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:197)
         at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
         at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 3
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 4 from BlockManagerMaster.
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 4 requested
17/04/14 18:12:35 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 4
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 11, (reason: Max number of executor failures (3) reached)
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk2/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-1f1b6198-961b-418d-9274-5f35f8e67829
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk6/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-fdce09f8-8677-45b2-9ce4-ac7134ab63b0
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk4/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-10c52d9a-a76b-465f-82d5-42eba9c89c86
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk5/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-4c492882-813a-4c2b-a041-ae69aba7ce00
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk3/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-1d9e6c60-fc33-45c3-8552-55cbe4266931
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk1/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-b6aa5cf9-042a-4804-9472-9bcddde2814e/userFiles-b259c206-d618-4d54-8630-824d955d0be4
17/04/14 18:12:38 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/disk1/yarn/nm/usercache/efinance/appcache/application_1488960736410_229415/spark-b6aa5cf9-042a-4804-9472-9bcddde2814e
```

Answer (score -1):

Reason might be the scala jar in my code is able to conflict with the scala jar in the cluster. when i deleted scala directory in the jar file of compiled and built maven project, it fixed the issue.